# PHP GAE - Upload and process large CSV with multiple queries per line

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have a Cloud SQL database with a list of people and their addresses (about 400,000 people). Every month, I receive an updated CSV file which I must check against the database for a) new people, b) changes in address, and c) removed people, which means running multiple queries per person.

I can successfully read the CSV file (150mb) on my local computer line by line and run the queries to the Cloud SQL database. My problem is that this is incredibly slow (less than 100 people processed per minute), and because GAE has a file upload limit of 32mb, I cannot upload the file and run it that on their server.

What is the fastest way to upload a CSV file with my PHP GAE app, and run multiple queries against each line in the file to update my Cloud SQL database?

Here is my sample script:

```
$import_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$file = fopen('local_path/monthly_data.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {

    $id                 = $line[0];
    $address            = $line[1];
    $name               = $line[2];

    $check_id = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM my_table WHERE id='$id'")->fetchColumn();
    if($check_id) { // The person already exists
        $check_address = $db->query("SELECT address FROM my_table WHERE id='$id'")->fetchColumn();
        if($check_address != $address) { // The address has changed
            $class->update_address($id, $address, $import_date);
        } else {
            $class->update_import_date($import_date);
        }
    } else {
        $class->add_person($id, $address, $name, $import_date);
    }
}

fclose($file);
```

After this is complete, I will check for rows with import_dates before `$import_date` to see which people are not in the latest monthly_data file.

Answer (score 2):

You could upload the CSV file directly to a Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket - 5TB object size limit - and adjust your app to process it from there. See  [Uploading Objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects).

You could also split locally the CSV file into multiple ones of acceptable size for uploading through your app. As a positive side effect this allows your app to process these files in parallel - even faster.